# Mongo concurrency with findAndModify()

Tags: mongodb

If two processes call this method with the same parameters at the same time, both finish their (same) query, and the first process gets the write lock on the document, does the second process then execute its modify operation after the first one finishes?  If so, does it still work with the original data it received, or with the updated data from the first query?